# How to get hostname or unique identification of computers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have an app (ASP.Net 3.1 Core MVC,SQL Server) that is deployed internally (network) wherein we can only access the app by using AnyConnect VPN. It is also given that we have a remote connection in an onsite computer.

Can you give me an idea or suggestions on how to identify the client if he/she is working at home or at the office. I tried searching here in SO on how to get Hostname , it works on the physically connected to the network computer at the office but it does not work when the app is accessed externally (through VPN).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Can you share the code which is working for HostName? And how are you using the hostname to determine whether user is connected via remote or not?

Comment: You're not going to be able to get the hostname of a computer through the client's browser. The best you can get is their OS, which can be spoofed, or their external IP, which might not be reliable or helpful.

Comment: @Chetan ‘’’ string hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).Hostname; ‘’’

Comment: @gunr2171 so you think there’s no work-around into my case?

Comment: The IPs of physically connected machines are issued by the DNS server, and they are local to the network and DNS server know the hostname mapped to the IPs it issued. That's why you are able to get the hostname using those IPs. The IPs of remotely connected machines are not the IPs of the actual machine but they are the IPs of the nearest hub or ISP, and they may not resolve to a host name as DNS do not know about the  those IPs.

Comment: What is the value you get of `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` for the remotely connected machine?

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello could you tell us why you want to do that ? what is your actual requirement that driven you to the solution of using the hostname ?

Comment: @Chetan it throws an error of an error occurred while processing your request, and this will stuck the app on error page

Comment: @iSR5 i need to determine if an employee works onsite or in office. I’m thinking getting their machine name or any sort of unique identifier of their machine

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello for what reason you need to know if the client onsite/office ? what you want to do with this information? because you might be taking the hard route here., and there most be another easier way to get the job done.

Comment: @iSR5 because our company needs to know who is the employee that are not complying to our plotted hybrid schedule.

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello so, you need the person and not the machine. Is onsite/office involvement would be required for that ? for instance,  if the company knows the employee, does it matter if the employee was connected from office or remotely ?